# How Do I Pass Array of Checked Items into Object in AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an input checkbox enclosed in `ng-repeat` with a function `vm.addRemoveItem()` for `ng-change` that stores all checked items in an array `vm.itemsArr`. I want to be able to pass the array to a c# method via webAPI but the array isn't passed into the variable I use. Please see the proper description in code below

**Checkbox in ng-repeat**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="vm.addRemoveItem()" value={{item.id}} /> {{item.title}}
```

**function that stores all checked items in an array**

```
vm.addRemoveItem = function () {
     vm.itemsArr = [];
     angular.forEach(vm.itemList, function (item) {
        if (item.selected) {
           vm.itemsArr.push(item.id);
        }
    })
}
```

I confirmed that the above function works as I was able to display the content of the array of checked items using `alert()`.

**Passing the values to c# through webAPI (My challenge)**

```
vm.itemObj= {
    itemInfoId: $stateParams.id,
    itemValues: JSON.stringify(vm.itemsArr)
};
```

The challenge here is when I pass the above object `itemObj` into the function that is called through webAPI, it returns validation error because `itemValues` is null but `itemInfoId` has the right value. How do I pass the content of the array into `itemValues`?

**C# Function**

```
public async Task AddSubjectToClassInfoAsync(AddItemsInput input)
{
   //Code to add values to database 
}

//AddItemsInput Class
public class AddSubjectsInput
{
    public int ItemInfoId { get; set; }

    public string[] ItemValues { get; set; }
}
```

**Angular Function Call**

```
vm.add = function () {
    subjectService.addtoDBAsync(vm.itemObj).success(function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    })
};
```

Comment: pls provide your web api method and ajax call

Comment: Define **vm.itemsArr = []** outside the function **vm.addRemoveItem**

Comment: Is your last piece of code be being initialised on load rather than at runtime?

Comment: Where is the piece of code where your vm.itemObj is being created? have you placed an alert just before it is created, to check that vm.itemsArr is populated

Comment: @UpalRoy Please see edited post. Thanks

Comment: @NNR I tried that. Still no joy.

Comment: @uk2k05 Yes I confirmed that vm.itemsArr is populated by using alert to check.

Comment: The code you pasted vm.itemObj = ... is this in the root of your controller or inside of a function?

Comment: @uk2k05 It is in the root of the controller.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle

Comment: Here lies your problem, it is being created before you have populated vm.itemsArr so the itemsValue will always be null. You should create this object before the Api call

Comment: @uk2k05 I thought as much. But can you show me how I can create the object after the array has been populated? Sorry I started using angularJS  barely a month ago. Thanks.

Comment: @uk2k05 YOU LIFESAVER!!! Your suggestion led me to creating the object inside the API call and it worked like a charm. Please how do I give you credit for this? I have been on this tiny problem for over 24hrs. Should I simply upvote your comment or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you placed the creation of vm.itemObj directly inside of the controller, it is being created as soon as the controller is built, this means vm.itemsArr has not yet been initialised or populated, so you are getting a null reference.

Change the creation of object vm.itemObj to;

```
vm.itemObj= {
    itemInfoId: $stateParams.id,
    itemValues: []
};
```

Now you can either push items to vm.itemObj.itemValues directly, or when required replace itemValues with another array probably at the point you are about to perform the api call.

```
vm.itemObj.itemValues = vm.itemsArr;
```

Comment: You're a superstar! Thanks. This also works for me. Check my last comment on the post itself. I already posted it before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to change array in parameter object to json string at

```
 itemValues: JSON.stringify(vm.itemsArr)
```

in place you can send array as it is

```
 vm.itemsArr
```

and http service will be using **vm.itemObj** Object

Comment: itemValues is still null.